# Postgresql select, show fixed count rows

Tags: postgresql, select, rows, minimum

Simple question. I have a table "tablename" with 3 rows. I need show 5 rows in my select when count rows < 5.

```
select * from tablename


+------------------+
|colname1 |colname2|
+---------+--------+
|1        |AAA     |
|2        |BBB     |
|3        |CCC     |
+---------+--------+
```

In this query I show all rows in the table.
But I need show 5 rows. 2 rows is empty.
For example (I need):

```
+------------------+
|colname1 |colname2|
+---------+--------+
|1        |AAA     |
|2        |BBB     |
|3        |CCC     |
|         |        |
|         |        |
+---------+--------+
```

Last 2 rows is empty.
It is possible?

Comment: What if you have more than 5 rows in the table?

Comment: I think this would be much easier to handle in your application layer.  What language are you using, or is this a pure DBA problem?

Comment: Thank you, all! Мery useful information for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
with num_rows (rn) as (
   select i
   from generate_series(1,5) i -- adjust here the desired number of rows
), numbered_table as (
   select colname1, 
          colname2,
          row_number() over (order by colname1) as rn
   from tablename
)
select t.colname1, t.colname2
from num_rows r
  left outer join numbered_table t on r.rn = t.rn;
```

This assigns a number for each row in `tablename` and joins that to a fixed number of rows. If you know that your values in `colname1` are always sequential and without gaps (which is highly unlikely) then you can remove the generation of row numbers in the second CTE using `row_number()`.

If you don't care *which* rows are returned, you can leave out the `order by` part - but then the rows that are matched will be *random*. Leaving out the `order by` will be a bit more efficient.

---

The above will always return exactly 5 rows, regardless of how many rows `tablename` contains. If you want *at least* 5 rows, then you need to flip the outer join:

```
....
select t.colname1, t.colname2
from numbered_table t
  left outer join num_rows r on r.rn = t.rn;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e5770/3